# Point Cloud point to map coordinates

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone please explain how can I transform a point (from a point cloud) to coordinate space of the map (which is built using gmapping)?

I've read the TF tutorials (http://ros.org/wiki/tf, http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials) but I still don't understand them well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34555/point-cloud-point-to-map-coordinates/) by [ZeroCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/2321/zerocool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The methods to transform points (and various other types) are members of the TransformListener class ([C++](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html), [Python](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html#tf.TransformerROS)). transformPoint is the method you're looking for.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZeroCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/2321/zerocool/) on 2012-05-22**:
Should I use base_link as frame id to make a correct transform?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-05-22**:
That depends what you're trying to accomplish. If you want the point to be in the /map frame, then you should transform into map.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-22**:
transformPoint() works for geometry_msgs/PointStamped. I suspect @ZeroCool is interested in sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are interested in `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` using C++, I recommend using one of the [`pcl_ros::transformPointCloud()` methods](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#a29cf585a248dc53517834f4c5a1c4d69).

As Dan said, you probably want to transform from whatever frame the message was published in to the "/map" frame.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-26**:
@joq @Dan Lazewatsky  im trying to acomplish something similar which is posted here,
http://answers.ros.org/question/83756/how-to-label-and-object-in-map/
I would really appreciate some help.